# How to wire a bathroom fan with a timer?

Tags: wiring, bathroom

From what I understand there are 3 ways to wire a bathroom fan:

1. Together with the lights (both are on or off);
2. Individual switches for lights and fan;
3. Put the fan (and maybe the light) on a presence sensor (which usually have a timer).

Now what I would like is to have a switch to turn the fan on and when the switch is turned off it remains on for a while. Is there a way to setup that?

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want the 'delayed off' switch rather than your standard timer switch? I'm not sure if what you are looking for actually exists.

Comment: Because my wife asked if it was possible. She doesn't like that the fan turns on every time someone just enters the bathroom (the 3 setup above). I don't know enough to know if this is feasible...

Comment: So what you want is your option #1, but with a delayed off in the fan circuit?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, something like that.

Comment: There are delayed-release circuits available for this purpose. But I'm not sure there's a version which would be an easy consumer install.

Comment: If the wiring is there to support it (separate switched hot for light and fan), a [humidity sensing switch](http://www.amazon.com/Leviton-IPHS5-1LW-Humidity-Sensor-Control/dp/B00H3QQD64) could be installed for the fan. Then the fan will automatically run whenever the humidity in the room is too high.

Comment: Is this an existing fan, or a new install?

Comment: New install, the wiring could be done to accommodate any setup.

Comment: BTW: are you 120V or 240V?

Comment: 127v per phase (Brazil).

Comment: All you need is to put the fan on a timer switch it sounds like. If the fan is on it's own switch now, just swap out the current switch with a timer. A person can turn it on if they want to, or not. If they turn it on, it will shut off automatically after a while.

Comment: I beleive panasonic sells fans with these features.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as too many wires between the bathroom switch and the bathroom light/fan/heatlamp/whatever the future may bring. I would run at least 3 hots and a neutral, with 1 hot and 1 neutral being 12ga for a high current device. Even better, install conduit and pull whatever as needed.

I personally hate fans which turn on with the light.  I fear I'll wake others during a 3AM bathroom run.  It also wastes energy by ejecting nice warm/cool air, forcing the HVAC system to work harder.

This forum is not for "shop for you", but there's no problem getting a [single switch that turns off the fan](http://amzn.to/273rNlA) some period after it turns off the light.  the fan with a delay. on light+fan, and turns off light and adand continues the fan for a designated period.

There's also no trouble getting [rundown timer switches](http://amzn.to/1UI7KEh) if you want to manually trigger the fan.  However if you also have a heatlamp (commonly put on rundown timers), this will be a confusing UI.

They even make [fan controls which detect humidity](http://amzn.to/273rNlA).  The question is whether they have, um... [VOC detection](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86311/what-affects-air-quality-indoors-after-home-improvement/86327#86327).

*Amazon links on SE pay a tiny commission to somebody, possibly me. It biases me toward linking products sold on Amazon.*